# Create a button in the bottom of the screen in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am wondering if there is way to create a button above a listView like in Twitter (the + in screen below).
I found a similar question but the button ocupy all the width, which is not my case.
Like the button is in the second plan.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can use `RelativeLayout` for example:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this UI component is called `Floating Action Button` (FAB). It's drawn above all UI elements.

From docs:

> Floating action buttons are used for a special type of promoted action. They are distinguished by a circled icon floating above the UI and have special motion behaviors related to morphing, launching, and the transferring anchor point.

Here is a tutorial how to add it: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/floating-action-button

Just add it to your layout where you define your `ListView` or `RecyclerView`